# Android Media player throwing error (-38, 0) after doing a reset() while playing files stored on the sd card

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a list of songs which may be stored locally in the SD card or may be streamed from the network.Tapping on a song starts playing the song.

When the list contains have all songs to be streamed from the network everything is working fine.

But When I have songs which are stored in the sd card then While a song is playing and I tap on another one the _mediaPlayer.reset() throws an error (-38,0)and code enters the onError function where what=-38 extra=0.

However the really confusing part is that when the player has all the locally stored song and the player is paused then tapping on another song works perfectly fine. It only throws the error when a song was being played. So I tried pausing a song if it is playing but it did not help.

PS: I am encrypting the local files and decrypting the file just before playing and storing the unencrypted file with a fixed name(Ex: current.mp3). I also delete the current.mp3 before deencrypting the ile.

I am using a service to play the songs.Below is the code relevant to my problem.

```
    private static class OnPreparedListener_r implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
    {
        Context ctx;
        public OnPreparedListener_r(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
        }
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Utils.acquireWakeLock();
            Utils.requestAudioFocus(ctx);
            mp.start();
      }
        //rest of the code
   }

    //code to play the song when the user taps on it    
/*
        if(_mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {   //this I tried adding to solve the issue
             pause();
        }
*/

            _mediaPlayer.reset();
            if(currentSong.isLocallyStored()){
                DeleteCurrFile();
                Decrypt(current_song);
            _   mediaPlayer.setDataSource("path to the local file ");
             }else{
           _mediaPlayer.setDataSource("streaming path ");
           }

            _mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();



//handling the error
   private static class OnErrorListener_r implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener
    {
        Context ctx;
        public OnErrorListener_r(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
        }
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            handleMediaError(ctx);  
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to figure out the problem for the last 3-4 days and went through all the links but could not find a good explanation of the error which could explain my situation. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I could not find a good solution but I put a hack to check for the error(-38,0) in which case what=-38 and extra=0. If it happens I handle it myself by starting the song again.

Comment: Did you find a way how to fix it.i am also getting the same error.

Comment: @AbhijitChakra No I did not find the solution and am still using the hack i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same error. I found the root reason:

After `MediaPlayer.reset`,use `getDuration` and `getCurrentPosition` methods.

Please refer to:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

where you can find:

There is a subtle but important difference between a newly constructed `MediaPlayer` object and the `MediaPlayer` object after `reset()` is called.

It is a programming error to invoke methods such as `getCurrentPosition()`, `getDuration()`, `getVideoHeight()`, `getVideoWidth()`, `setAudioStreamType(int)`, `setLooping(boolean)`, `setVolume(float, float)`, `pause()`, `start()`, `stop()`, `seekTo(int)`, `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()` in the Idle state for both cases.

If any of these methods is called right after a MediaPlayer object is constructed, the user supplied callback method `OnErrorListener.onError()` won't be called by the internal player engine and the object state remains unchanged; but if these methods are called right after `reset()`, the user supplied callback method `OnErrorListener.onError()` will be invoked by the internal player engine and the object will be transfered to the Error state.

In my code, I use `TimerTask` to get `getCurrentPosition` and `getDuration`.